# Calling a function based on a Listbox current selection "curselection()" in Tkinter

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

I have a listbox on a GUI in Tkinter. I would like to implement a routine where if a listbox item is selected a function is called (based on this selection) to modify the gui (add another adjacent listbox). Then if that selection changes, the gui reverts back to its default view. Can this be done? Seems you would need to associate a function to a listbox selection, not sure how to do this or if its possible... Does anyone have the secret?

Its possible to add "select" buttons to the bottom of my listbox, but I wanted to avoid this extra work for user and save space on the GUI.

Thanks to all in advance! Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listbox will fire the virtual event `<<ListboxSelect>>` whenever the selection changes. If you bind to it, your function will be called whenever the selection changes, even if it was changed via the keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

Ok nevermind, the link below answers my question with the example below:

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def callback(event):
    print "clicked at", event.x, event.y 

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

(replace frame with listbox widget of course)
Works !

Comment: Normally, binding to `<1>` on a listbox won't quite do what you expect. The binding will fire _before_ the item you clicked on is selected. Plus, it won't work if the selection is changed via rht keyboard. Instead, you should bind on `<<ListboxSelect>>`, which will fire _after_ the item is selected.

Comment: Thank You. And my apologies, didnt see your reply when I posted.